# struct.pack gives different results when calling it again after reassigning one of its inputs

Tags: python, struct, bytebuffer, icmp

I am writing a Python script to send ICMP packets by following an example from a [Japanese website](https://euniclus.com/article/python-route-scan/).
There is part of the code where `struct.pack` is used to pack series of variables into a bytes array.
It looks somehow like the following:

```py
import struct

def make_icmp_echo_request():
    _type = 8
    code = 0
    check = 0
    _id = 1
    seq = 1

    packed = struct.pack("!BBHHH", _type, code, check, _id, seq)
    return packed

make_icmp_echo_request()
```

No matter how much you call `make_icmp_echo_request`, the output will be the same.
However, the website also implements a `checksum` function which will be used after the ICMP packet is packed.
The weird thing is that the implementation from the website will call `struct.pack` one more time after the call to `checksum`.
Something like below:

```py
import struct

def checksum(data):
    data_len = len(data) // 2 * 2
    csum = 0
    for i in range(0, data_len, 2):
        csum += (data[i + 1] << 8) + data[i]
    if len(data) % 2 != 0:
        csum += data[-1]
    while csum >> 16:
        csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
    csum = csum >> 8 | (csum << 8 & 0xff00)
    return ~csum&0xffff

def make_icmp_echo_request():
    _type = 8
    code = 0
    check = 0
    _id = 1
    seq = 1

    packed = struct.pack("!BBHHH", _type, code, check, _id, seq)
    check = checksum(packed)
    return struct.pack("!BBHHH", _type, code, check, _id, seq)

make_icmp_echo_request()
```

I found out that the output of the first call to `struct.pack` is different from the second one.
And this only happens if `checksum` is being called after the first call.

I confirmed this with below code (I also unpacked back the packed byte array to make things clearer).

```py
import struct

def checksum(data):
    data_len = len(data) // 2 * 2
    csum = 0
    for i in range(0, data_len, 2):
        csum += (data[i + 1] << 8) + data[i]
    if len(data) % 2 != 0:
        csum += data[-1]
    while csum >> 16:
        csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
    csum = csum >> 8 | (csum << 8 & 0xff00)
    return ~csum&0xffff


def make_icmp_echo_request():
    _type = 8
    code = 0
    check = 0
    _id = 1
    seq = 1

    for i in range(10):
        print(f"[{i}]")
        packed = struct.pack("!BBHHH", _type, code, check, _id, seq)
        check = checksum(packed)
        print(packed, check)
        unpacked = struct.unpack("!BBHHH", packed)
        print(unpacked)

    return packed

make_icmp_echo_request()
```

```
*** Loop: 0 ***
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01' 63485
(8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 1 ***
b'\x08\x00\xf7\xfd\x00\x01\x00\x01' 0
(8, 0, 63485, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 2 ***
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01' 63485
(8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 3 ***
b'\x08\x00\xf7\xfd\x00\x01\x00\x01' 0
(8, 0, 63485, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 4 ***
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01' 63485
(8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 5 ***
b'\x08\x00\xf7\xfd\x00\x01\x00\x01' 0
(8, 0, 63485, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 6 ***
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01' 63485
(8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 7 ***
b'\x08\x00\xf7\xfd\x00\x01\x00\x01' 0
(8, 0, 63485, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 8 ***
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01' 63485
(8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
*** Loop: 9 ***
b'\x08\x00\xf7\xfd\x00\x01\x00\x01' 0
(8, 0, 63485, 1, 1)
```

Can anyone explain this?
It is also weird that the ICMP request will fail if I use the result of the first call to `struct.pack`.

Comment: Well, yes; if you use the values `_type, code, check, _id, seq` to create the packet, and then you *reassign `check` using the result of the function* (the code `check = checksum(packed)`, and re-try creating the packet, then of course the packet will have a different value. Why would you expect any different? Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: The OP missed a subtlety about checksum computation that's tripped up many programmers over the decades. And it will trip up more in decades to come. IMO, no favor was done by making it harder for them to find the easy answer. There was no typo here, and it remains wholly reproducible - the _given_ reason for closing it makes no sense. No, it's not a "profound" question, and is easily answered by someone not suffering the same blind spot - but that's true of most questions here.

Comment: @TimPeters agreed. I vote to reopen.

Comment: Can you clarify the title? "different" compared to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    check = 0
    ...
    packed = struct.pack("!BBHHH", _type, code, check, _id, seq)
    check = checksum(packed)
    return struct.pack("!BBHHH", _type, code, check, _id, seq)
```

The first call to `pack()` passes 0 for `check`. Then `check` is rebound to the result of the `checksum()` call. The second call to `pack()` uses this new value of `check`. So of course the results are different, if and only if `checksum()` doesn't return 0.

Comment: I still find this pattern awkward. Any reason I'm missing for having a zero value encoded into the first call? To validate the checksum a user would still have to parse the struct, strip out the checksum field and then reparse. Seems like it would make more sense to exclude the checksum altogether from the first value and place it at the end of the final struct?

Comment: @flakes the checksum is based on the values of the other fields in the struct. The check-summing function could have just been written to use the individual values, but it's intended to be a byte-level checksum, so that would have been awkward. Specifying a zero value for the checksum field gives the correct result for "checksum of the other values" (not every checksum would work that way). I agree that it would make more sense to design the packet such that the checksum is at the end, but this code might be implementing an existing protocol and thus not have that liberty.

Comment: The computation of ICMP checksums is specified in RFC 792, and hasn't changed in over 40 years ;-) Code implementing it has no choice. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792